# Differences between Being, Existing, Ontical and Existential in "Being and Time"

Tags: metaphysics, ontology, existentialism, phenomenology, heidegger

I am trying to understand the differences between Being, Ontical and Existential. What are they trying to imply by themselves, separately?

- Ontical seems to mean "physical existence".
- Existential seems to mean "metaphysical side of existence".

How to understand each meaning separately? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe useful some introduction... See e.g. Paul Gorner, [Heidegger's Being and Time: An Introduction (Cambridge UP, 2007)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Heidegger_s_Being_and_Time/GK6GJTR816IC), Index: being, existence (*Dasein*), ontic/ontological distinction

Comment: In a sense, all the book is about the meaning of "being", starting from the fundamental difference between "a being", i.e. an entity that *is*, and the "being" of the entity (that is not itself an entity).

Comment: Related [Ontic vs. Ontological](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/47711/9148). See also Wikipedia article on [Heideggerian terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heideggerian_terminology).

Comment: @Conifold I appreciate that, thank you very much!