# Ontic/Ontological as parallel to a posteriori/a priori?

Tags: kant, ontology, heidegger, phenomenology, hermeneutics

Heidegger makes the distinction between the **ontic** (concerning beings themselves) and the **ontological** (the being of beings, being as such).

Would it be wise to say that the ontic covers the contingent possibilities concerning beings and the ontological concerns the universal and necessary structures that makes those beings possible? (a posteriori/priori)

One place where I can see this definition failing is that suddenly the ontic sciences, physics for example, are now “degraded” to studying just the contingent possibilities of beings, which hardly seems like the right categorization. In this definition, however, the sentence “*the ontic fact that Dasein is ontological*” makes much more sense, along with “*the ontological fact that Dasein is pre-ontological.*”

Comment: Not really, necessary/contingent are analytic terms that Heidegger is not concerned with, and a priori/ a posteriori are even further. Your could say crudely that ontic is about essence/descriptive and ontological is about existence/visceral, see [Heideggerian terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heideggerian_terminology#Existence#Ontic) and [Ontic vs. Ontological](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/47711/9148) here.